# Where is "Create disk image" function in El Capitan/Sierra?

Tags: hard-drive, macos

Updated today to Sierra from Yosemite. Can't find disk backup function in new Disk Utility...

Comment: In El Capitan it is located under **File > New Image**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Disk Utility, you can use "New Image from Folder" accessible under `File > New Image > Image from Folder` or by <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Navigate to Computer or Volumes in the window and select your disk as the folder to create the image from. This should create an image of the disk.

Comment: That's it, but doesn't work with hard drives xD - error 5.